# Autocomplete suggestion not working properly when we call the value form url

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, tags, jquery-tageditor

We are using TagEditor for defining the tag in the post if when we give the static auto-suggestion work fine. When we try to define the URL it calls value auto-suggestion not working properly its call its all value and arrow suggestion not working. In URL we call vale of any array-like something as this ["New1","Offer","New","test","app"]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tag').tagEditor({
            autocomplete: { 
                delay: 0, position: 
            { collision: 'flip' }, 
         'source': '{{ URL::to('admin/category/tagname') }}',
            cache:false,
            forceLowercase: false,
            placeholder: 'Tag'
        } 
            
        });

    });
```

If we used it instead of this code it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tag').tagEditor({
            autocomplete: { 
                delay: 0, position: 
            { collision: 'flip' }, 
         source: '["New1","Offer","New","test","app"]',
            cache:false,
            forceLowercase: false,
            placeholder: 'Tag'
        } 
            
        });

    });
```

Comment: I don't understand `when we call the url its call all value`. What does this mean? What's the expected behaviour and what's the current one?

Comment: used url to call the value from database in the from of array

Comment: ...which means? I'm struggling to understand what you mean. Again, what is the expected behaviour and what is the current one? Don't say `We do stuff with things from the database array with url thingy`. Edit your question, explain clearly what exactly is happening and what exactly you are trying to do. Problems must be clear, if an answer is to be expected.

Comment: now check question updated to you i think now its helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but really I'm sorry, I'm trying to understand what you mean but I can't. I read three times slowly `it calls value auto-suggestion not working properly its call its all value and arrow suggestion not working` but really I can't understand what it means and what the problem is. Also, saying "it's not working" [is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/), that's why I asked you several times to describe the current behaviour and the desired one, but still you didn't.

Comment: At least I can say that `'source': '{{ URL::to('admin/category/tagname') }}'`is invalid. You are using single quotes inside single quotes, so it produces a syntax error. It should be `'source': "{{ URL::to('admin/category/tagname') }}"` (double quotes around, so you can use single quotes inside)